# Retrieve path of file from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, fileoutputstream

My file is resides in servlet application in same package where java class is stored i want pass that location to FIleoutputStream i tried for getResourceAsStream ,directly providing that path but it's not working

Comment: Please provide the directories layout of you application, where the servlet resides, where is the file, and how exactly you call your file (a code snippet)

Comment: Puh, what exactly does 'it's not working' mean? Please provide the relevant code snieppts and the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the file is relative to WEB-INF/classes folder. So what you are giving as argumnet in the getResourceAsStream method? That should solve it.